# How do I redirect shell stdout to the first line of file?

Tags: bash, shell

The shell standard output redirects to the last line of the file, is there a way to write it to the first line of the file?

Since the content of stdout is unpredictable, I suspect that this may require changing the default behavior of stdout, but I am not sure if it is feasible.

Example, redirecting a timestamp to file

```
echo `date` >> test.txt
```

Default save to last line of file

```
Mon Aug 31 00:40:27 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:28 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:29 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:30 UTC 2020
```

Desired effect, save the output to the first line of the file

```
Mon Aug 31 00:40:30 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:29 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:28 UTC 2020
Mon Aug 31 00:40:27 UTC 2020
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would examining the file in reverse order suite your use case?  Try `tac test.txt`

Comment: [What is wrong with `echo $(date)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To write the date to the beginning instead of the end of `file`, try:

```
{ date; cat file; } >file.new && mv file.new file
```

#### Discussion

1. Adding new text to the beginning of a file requires the whole file to be rewritten.  Adding new text to the end of a file only requires writing the new text.
2. [Andy Dalton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/90691/andy-dalton)'s suggestion of just appending to the end of a file like normal and then using `tac file` to view the file is a good one.
3. `` echo `date` >> test.txt `` can be replaced by a simpler and more efficient `date >> test.txt`.

   If one is using bash 4.3 or later then, as [Charles Duffy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3113/charles-duffy) points out, `printf '%(%c)T\n' -1 >>test.txt` is still more efficient.
4. The spaces around the curly braces are essential.  This is because `{` and `}` are shell *reserved words* (as opposed to shell *keywords* which do not require spaces).

Comment: If one is using bash 4.3 or later, `printf '%(%c)T\n' -1 >>test.txt` is even more efficient than `date >>test.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very good.  I just added  `printf '%(%c)T\n' -1 >>test.txt` to the answer.

Comment: `mv` does not overwrite; you need to use  `...>file.new && rm file && mv file.new file` or  `...>file.new && mv -f file.new file`.

Comment: @Naghi By default, It is common for users to have shell aliases set in `~/.bashrc` or elsewhere that override default behaviors.  In the case of `mv`, such an alias may apply the `-i` option to make overwrites interactive or the `-n` option to prevent them altogether.  Without such an override, it is the default behavior for `mv` simply and quietly overwrite an existing target file.

Answer (score 12):

Try using `sed` :

```
sed -i "1 i\
$(date)" test.txt
```

Form `man` :

> i \ 
> text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse order of lines

```
ex -s +%g/^/m0 +wq file
```

`ex -s` mode of vim editor, equivalent `vim -nes`
`+wq` command save and exit
or for bash

```
tac <<<$(<file) >file
```

`<<<$(<file)` this design serves as a self-made buffer

Writing to the first line

```
cat <<<$(date)$'\n'$(<file) >file
echo -e "$(date)\n$(<file)" >file
```

and

```
ex -s +'0r!date' +wq file
```

Sorry, I didn't get it right at first

Comment: This should be `<<<"$(<file)"` and, later, `<<<"$(date)"$'\n'"$(<file)"` to avoid a bug in versions of bash older than 4.3 where herestring contents were, when unquoted, subject to string-splitting (followed by being re-joined on the first character in IFS).

Comment: I would also strongly suggest replacing `echo -e "$(date)\n$(<file)"` with `printf '%s\n' "$(date)" "$(<file)"` for the reasons described in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) -- to summarize, even if the shell is certain to be bash, how `echo -e` behaves depends on flags that can be modified at compile-time or runtime; when bash's `echo` is behaving in a standards-compliant way, `echo -e foo` prints `-e foo` on output, instead of treating `-e` as an option to consume.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```bsh
echo `date` > test.txt
```

truncates the file test.txt and writes into it

While the command

```bsh
echo `date` >> test.txt
```

writes to the file appending to the end

There is not a way in the shell to write without writing at the end (either by first truncating or by appending).

Lines are just a bunch of files with a delimiter. Prepending a line requires rewriting the whole file. However, it is possible to open a file for read-write and overwrite the existing bytes. Although the shell doesn't give you a direct interface for that, you may use for instance `dd` to get such effect:

```bsh
date | dd of=test.txt conv=notrunc
```

This would *replace* the first date with the current one. Also note that we are taking advantage that it is outputting in a format with a fixed width,* so we are just replacing the first record. Otherwise, if each line had different length, we would probably end up with a mess of partial ends of old lines written at the beginning of the file.

(*) Beware that if the timezone varies, so does the length. Specially when changing from/to DST. `date -R` would be a more stable format.

Comment: Since NULs aren't rendered by an ANSI-compliant terminal, one could have a file start with a fixed length of nothing but NULs, and later replace that block with an updated header and the same number of NULs; it would look like the changing first line, and would be able to modify its length so long as it never overruns the NUL-padded region.